# Creating wysiwyg preview for a custom math functions on lyx

Tags: lyx, wysiwyg

Let's say I want to create a "macro" called `\limx` that will be defined as:

```
\newcommand{\limx}{\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\x_{0}}}}
```

How can I make LyX recognize it and make an auto-prieview of it?

Another example, I'm using the [cancel](http://anrg.usc.edu/~joonahn/www/index.php/Canceling_Terms_in_LaTeX_Math) package. When I'm using `\cancel` in a math equation it doesn't preview it while editing. I can still see "`\cancel`" on the equation editor. Only when I render the document the `\cancel` is being really rendered. How can I add that functionality to the LyX's WYSIWYG environment as well?

Comment: Which version of LyX do you use?  I have version 1.6.7 and when using the `cancel` package, `\cancel` previews just fine.  So do macros that I define in the preamble.

Comment: @Dave: Why the `mathmode` tag?

Comment: @Jan: My mistake.

Comment: @Jan I'm using Lyx 1.6.7, but when i use "\cancel" it doesn't work for me. I still just see "\cancel" in the mathmode...

Comment: In the equation editor, when actually editing the formula, it will use `\cancel`. As far as I know, there is no way to teach LyX a graphical representation of new macros that it doesn't already know. When you are done with editing, and leave the particular "equation" (I think it is "math inset" in LyXspeak), LyX should preview the formula just the way it will look in the compiled document.  At that moment, `\cancel` should render the way it is supposed to.  When you click on the equation again, you will enter edit mode, and and you will see `cancel` again.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand things, it's not necessary to do anything special for macros that get used inside equations; LyX just runs them through LaTeX and (with the aid of `preview.sty`) extracts the preview images.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at hand. I'm also working on creating previews in Lyx for custom Latex classes, and its not really all that straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but in case someone runs across this later - it's possible to turn on Instant Preview, to, well, instantly preview insets. Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/InstantPreview), but if you're on Windows it's as simple as going to Tools > Preferences and activating Instant Preview.

Comment: I've defined a series of variables in this way: `\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mathrm{#1}} \newcommand{\Coll}{\var{Coll}} \newcommand{\LDG}{\var{LGD}} \newcommand{\EAD}{\var{EAD}}` etc. but when I activate Instat Preview they disappear. It works if I use every time `\var{Coll}` etc.

Comment: I gave a slightly more detailed explanation of this answer here; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499152/render-preview-commands-stored-in-external-file-in-lyx/499169#499169