# Use custom latex package in LyX

Tags: packages, lyx

I just downloaded the package `stmaryrd` and have a LyX LaTeX Beamer document in which I want to insert some symbols with this package (`\llbracket`). Is there a way to make LyX include the package in the file, without having to edit the underlying document outside of LyX? Thanks!

Comment: If you ever [wanted to know what package to use for any other symbol](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), you'd think this question was a little restricted! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LyX has an option to edit the LaTeX preamble (under *Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble*), and in there you can insert:

`\usepackage{stmaryrd}`

And then you can insert the symbols you need using its feature for inserting LaTeX codes directly.

Getting the symbols to appear correctly in the LyX preview screen is another matter, and probably very difficult if not impossible, however.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please give me the exact menu/button names? I've been looking like mad. There is no menu item "Layout" and I can't find anything that works in the menu "Document".

Comment: @Felix: I change the menu path to what I think is correct (I have never actually used LyX).

Comment: @Caramdir: thank you so much! (I feel extremely stupid now for not finding it though ...)

Comment: Sorry I must have been looking an an older/different version of LyX. I don't even have it installed anymore.

Comment: I've also been looking like mad as to how to get custom latex packages to render in preview in lyx...
I found a similar question, I really would like to see either question answered: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6525/creating-wysiwyg-preview-for-a-custom-math-functions-on-lyx

Comment: @frabjous where should I put the file I've downloaded from CTAN? How does Lyx knows about the package if it's not downloaded yet?

Comment: @bobsacameno You should install the package with your TeX distribution's package manager rather than simply downloading it from CTAN. LyX doesnt need to know about it; only LaTeX does.

Comment: @frabjous and how do I install that? (I'm using a Mac)

Comment: @bobsacameno Why am I not surprised you're using a mac? Google how to install a package with your TeX distribution's package manager. Without even knowing what TeX distribution you're using, it's a bit hard for me to guess.