# Stop table going off page

Tags: tables, lyx

I'm aware that my table is too wide as it keeps going off the page on the right.

Is there a way to fix this?

I'm using lyx as I am a learner.

Comment: Many users end up here when they are actually searching for how to wrap text in a table row. Answer is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332712/getting-text-to-wrap-in-lyx-table-cells

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
... your tabular ...
}
```

In LyX insert the two lines in ERT (Evil Red Text) mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>) just before and after your tabular. In the documents preamble add `\usepackage{graphicx}` if not already present.

This is how you add a new package: [Use custom latex package in LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9112/use-custom-latex-package-in-lyx)

Comment: it works! but I'm getting a compilation error on lyx. Any idea on how to solve it? (again, it is able to compile the pdf)

Comment: what error message? Did yoo loaded `graphicx`?

Comment: If you are getting an error.  Try switching out of longtable mode by right clicking the table-->More-->Settings-->and unchecking longtable

Comment: This does the wrong thing. It scales the entire table instead of doing overflow in the columns.

Comment: it depends on what you want!

Comment: It's worth noting that if your table is inside a float, the LaTeX code in the ERT goes inside the float environment as well

Comment: @Herbert, I used this but does not work.

Comment: Then your image is too big. Try `\resizebox{!}{0.9\textheight}{...}`

Comment: Is it possible to integrate this into the preamble such that it auto-boxes LyX tables? It may be impossible because LyX uses its own thing `\begin_inset Tabular`.

Answer (score 9):

You can fix the width of the table to fit the width of your general text.

To fix the width of the table in LyX 2.0, right-click in a cell in the column, move to `More...` and choose `Settings...`. In the `Table Settings` tab, you can set the value near the bottom, under `Table-wide settings`.

This, however, will set the width of your table, but not the content of the table. If, e.g., you have a cell with a lot of text that extends beyond the margin, then also pick a width for that (those) column(s) under `Column settings` in the same tab. This will also allow line breaks in the text.

Comment: That should be the selected answer, as the current one doesn't use LyX capabilities, but hard coded directives `\noindent\resizebox`