# Stop table going off page (vertically)

Tags: tables, lyx, margins

Much like [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49925/stop-table-going-off-page), I want to force a table to fit within the vertical page margins.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Margin size: `\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,textheight=23.5cm]{geometry}`

Present situation:
[image: Output and LyX text.]

Comment: Put it in a box and scale it to the text height.  It would help us help you if you gave us a minimum working example to start with.

Comment: I have edited my question to elaborate on my problem. By "box", do you mean float? @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: By box, I mean something like `\newsavebox\mybox\sbox{\mybox}{your table goes here}\scalebox{scale factor}{\usebox{\mybox}}`, where `\scalebox` is part of the `graphicx` package.  `scale factor` is a number.  The picture helps, but the code you used to get there would be more helpful, so that those who are willing to help you don't have to retype it all from scratch.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code. I am using LyX/LaTeX at a rookie level and I just follow the classicthesis template. I thought there would  be a similar one-liner like `\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ table here }` to make the table fit within the vertical margins. Anyway, your answer seem to work, thank you, but you have written it as a comment.

Comment: If you would like, I will turn it into an answer, using typical tabular material.

Comment: Please do, and I will accept it.

It just frustrates me that I can't get the `geometry` package to work my way. From the LyX wiki it is described how to fit the table horizontally by keeping the aspect ratio of your table, using `!` as the height parameter: `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{argument}`.

Comment: One last point:  if your table is exceeding the vertical limit of `\textheight`, but is within the horizontal extent of `\textwidth`, then the `\resizebox` macro you cite will not shrink the table, since it is already less wide than `\textwidth`.

Comment: That is my exact situation and problem. Do you know if any command similar to `\resizebox` within `geometry` is able of resizing tables vertically? I.e. tables breaking the vertical but not hortizontal extent of `\textwidth`.

Comment: Well, it won't work with a float, but if it is just the `tabular` you need resized, then my `scalerel` package has a macro `\scaleto{tabular material goes here}{\textheight}`

Comment: You are a goldmine. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my comment, I advocated something like:

```
\newsavebox\mybox
\sbox{\mybox}{your table goes here}
\scalebox{scale factor}{\usebox{\mybox}}
```

where `scalefactor` is a number and `your table` is something like a `tabular`.  In this illustrative example below, I first set the text height shorter (2.8")  just so it is easier to see what is going on.  The first thing I do I set a large tabular without any changes.  Because it exceeds the length of page 1, it ends up on page 2, and you see that it stretches down to the page number.

So, after clearing a page, I show how placing the table into a box and scaling it to a size smaller than unity can resolve the height issue (page 3).  Of course, the font size is no longer uniform through the document.

On page 4, I show how this approach can be incorporated into a float, such as a table.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\textheight 2.8in
\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Variable & description of the variable\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\par
}
\clearpage
\newsavebox\mybox
\sbox{\mybox}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Variable & description of the variable\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
{\centering\scalebox{.9}{\usebox{\mybox}}\par}
\clearpage
\begin{table}
\caption{My caption}
{\centering\scalebox{.85}{\usebox{\mybox}}\par}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the table to be scaled is not a float, but merely a `tabular`, it can be scaled exactly to the `\textheight` using the `\scaleto{object}{height}` feature of the `scalerel` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\textheight 6in
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\mybox
\sbox{\mybox}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Variable & description of the variable\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
Variable & description\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
{\centering\scaleto{\usebox{\mybox}}{\textheight}\par}

\end{document}
```