# Side by Side figures

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I have been trying to put side by side figures and have tried many options but couldn't get the success. I want to put 3 images as following attached image WITH CAPTIONS. If someone can help me, that would be awesome [I did try and search A LOT... Like REALLY A LOT]. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [subcaption package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). The following code produces the output below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % just for the boxes
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{4.2cm}
    \tikz\draw(0,0)rectangle(4,9);
    \caption{Caption1}\label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \quad
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{4.2cm}
      \tikz\draw(0,0)rectangle(4,4);
      \caption{Caption2}\label{fig:2}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{4.2cm}
      \tikz\draw(0,0)rectangle(4,4);
      \caption{Caption3}\label{fig:3}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Main caption}\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how should I install this package in Lyx?

Comment: I don't use lyx, but you probably find information with google, like here: [Use custom latex package in LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9112/use-custom-latex-package-in-lyx)